# How to fix Docker connection reset by peer, Docker Status is UP but cannot connect to sever?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

Having this issue of connection reset by peer when doing a curl to to docker server.
curl 127.0.0.1:8080

Also cannot access the server from browser, but docker status says: **UP 4 hours ago**
How can one fix this?

tried the following commands and docker seems to work fine but becomes unaccessible after few minutes.

```
docker build -t abelakponine/dockerimage .
docker run -p 0:8080 -itd --name imagename abelakponine/dockerimage
docker ps -a
docker logs --follow dockerprocessId
```

Here's what my dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.11.6
COPY . /App
WORKDIR /App

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

EXPOSE 8080

CMD apt -y update \
        && python3 --version \
        && hostname -I \
        && curl -4 icanhazip.com \
        && pip install -r requirements.txt \
        && pip install waitress gunicorn django-livereload-server whitenoise \
        && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So to solve this issue is simple, after many trials I figured what the problem is.

First of all, the port mapping **0:8080** was set to a port that was not listening on the server, so I corrected this to **8080:8080**

Secondly I added **--network host** to the run command, this tell the docker server to run on the host server

**Note:** Since we are adding `--network host` there's no need for including `-p 8080:8080` as this becomes redundant.

the complete code looks like this:

```
docker run --network host --name testimage -itd abelakponine/testimage
```

also do

```
docker logs --follow cointainerId
```

to view running docker logs

doing:

```
netstat -lnt
```

shows the running port: **127.0.0.1:8080**

Comment: `--network host` is almost never necessary; it conflicts with the `-p` option; and it doesn't work on Docker Desktop or other similar VM-based setups.  Do you actually need to disable Docker networking, or is fixing the `-p` option on its own enough?

Comment: @DavidMaze you are correct, the answer has been modified to remove `-p 8080:8080` as that becomes redundant due to adding `--network host`

Comment: To reiterate, `--network host` doesn't work on Docker Desktop or several other Docker setups, and it disables core Docker features like networking between containers.  I would not recommend it as a solution to a simple connectivity problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze well, it depends on the system's requirements I'd say, as far as I know this works fine on the specific requirements for Linux Ubuntu, not sure about other systems as I don't use those, in terms of networking between containers, there's always a work around that and definitely can run multiple containers smoothly.

Comment: @DavidMaze for some reason it doesn't just work without adding `--network` it doesn't actually has to be `host` depends on the user's needs and setup, but in my case that was what I needed, maybe I'll look into why it wasn't working without the network option when I've got the time.